# Prolog Variable

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have a small problem when we are talking about anonymous variables. For example when we make this:

```
?- [_,2]=[X|Y].
Y=[2].
```

but my question is about the variable X. Does it have the '_'?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238492/prolog-anonymous-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `X` does not "have the `_`". It is bound to an anonymous variable, which is never bound to anything else. This binding of `X` to an anonymous variable does not create any additional limitations on `X` - for all practical purposes, it remains unbound.

The `_` variable has been introduced to let Prolog coders express in code that they do not care about a value in a particular position. One could emulate this behavior by using variables that look like `UNUSED1`, `UNUSED2`, `UNUSED3` and so on instead of the `_`, and ignoring Prolog warnings about singleton variables:

```
[UNUSED123,2]=[X|Y].
```

Using the underscore `_` is like telling Prolog that you know that the unused variable is singleton, and that it is indeed your intention.

Comment: My original problem was to unify this two lists [2] and [1,_,3] giving an answer of [1,2,3]. I though of using the operator `|` to compare if the member we were spliting would unify through the predicate `member` (pre-built) but since I can't identify the `_` i don't know how to do it.
My code is:
    unifica([],[],_).
    unifica(Lista1, [Cabeca|Resto], Lista2) :-member(Lista1,Cabeca),!,
                                             unifica([X|_], Resto, [X|Lista2]).
    unifica(Lista1, [Cabeca|Resto], [Cabeca|Lista2]) :- unifica(Lista1, Resto, Lista2).

Comment: @Miguel Your code in the comment is hard to read because of formatting. You may want to post the actual problem that you are trying to solve as a separate question - it should get more attention this way.

Comment: Ok, i'll open a new question for this, thank for the above information